# What is the relationship between tables?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities which are user, group and subgroup.

A group can have multiple users. A group can have multiple subgroups.

```
User
-Id
-GroupId
-Name

Group
-Id
-GroupName

Subgroup
-Id
-GroupId
-SubGroupName
```

What is the relationship between User and Subgroup? I initially thought it would be many to many. But a user can have only one group and subgroups are belong to one group. So I think I might be wrong.

Also, would it enough to have 1 join table which is User_Subgroup or one more join table User_Group is needed?

Comment: You mean, what is the cardinality of the relationship. The relation(ship)/association is something like "user User is a member of subgroup Subgroup"--except you don't acutally say what the relationship is, so you are expecting us to guess from names & common sense.

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following your textbook with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems & algorithms you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs.

Answer (score 0):

As shown, `User` to `Group` is 1:1. Since `Group` to `Subgroup` is 1:N, `User` to `Subgroup` is also 1:N.

You don't need any join tables at all. `Group` will serve as a join between `User` and `Subgroup`. Join tables are only necessary to maintain N:N relationships, and there aren't any of those in your schema.

As an aside, if you are able to modify the table schemas, you'll be happier in the long run changing the `ID` column names to include the table name, e.g. `UserID` in the `User` table, `GroupID` in the `Group` table. It will be much clearer that `UserID` in `Group` joins to `UserID` in `User`, for instance.